# How to deal with presence of variables in message bundles ( localization )

Tags: java, spring, localization

it's the first time I'm developing an app that needs to be localized into more than 20 languages. The problem is that there is a lot of messages that contain a variable. It can't be hardcoded because if it changed, the administrator would have to change it in 20+ property files.

Are there any known possibilities how to deal with it ? I'm currently using spring framework.

Comment: There's a tutorial here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageintro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One methodology could be to replace variables with markers and use the String.Format method ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...) ) or another kind of Formatter to replace accordingly.

Whilst I'm just getting into Spring myself and suspect that it could provide a more elegant solution, currently I would use string formatters to replace placeholders with variable values at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `org.springframework.context.MessageSource`. There are various getMessage() methods which take an Object[] that can be used for variable substitution using `{0}`, `{1}`, syntax.

See [Section 3.13.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) of the Spring manual for more info.